# How can I make the code choose one of the items from the list, print it and repeat the process again and again?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make the program choose one of the items from the list, print it and repeat the process again and again.

I tried to create a boolean for the loop and the time.sleep doesn't seem to do something.

```
import random
import time

sounds=["Kick", "Hi-Hat", "Snare"]

beat=random.choice(sounds)

while True:
print(beat)
time.sleep(0.5)
```

It was supposed to print random items infinitely with a sleep of half a second but every time I run the program it just picks a random item and prints it again and again really fast (sorry for the bad English, I'm Portuguese).

Comment: Think about how many times `random.choice` is run.

Comment: of course it's happening really fast, it's only sleeping half a second

Comment: @aws_apprentice It is happening way faster than 0.5 secs

Comment: @DanHasAPan pretty sure that's not correct given you have specified to sleep half a second, you're saying there is a bug in `time.sleep`? highly unlikely

Comment: @memememe OH MAN THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only selecting the random item once and then running the loop. Try putting the random function inside the loop like this:

```
while True:
    beat=random.choice(sounds)
    print(beat)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

If it's faster than 0.5 seconds in your code it's probably because you've indented it bad and only the `print` statement falls inside the `while` loop. Be sure to indent everything that should be inside the loop with 4 spaces like I did here.

Comment: Hey @DanHasAPan if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.